# Lower downloading speed on my laptop than on my Desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, laptop

I have a laptop and a desktop PC. Both have Windows 7. I did a speedtest on both of them and here are the results:

- laptop 1.11mb/s
- desktop 5.56mb/s

Why these two are so different ? I am conected throught ethernet and then plugged in switch which goes to my desktop and laptop.
I tried to troubleshoot on Windows: No errors. I then tried to plug out the switch and directly to my laptop, but no diffrence

Where does the problem comes from ? I had identical download speed like 5 days ago when i was downloading battlefield 3 and now I am downloading battlefield 4 with 1MB/s ?

Here is a little sketch of how is my Network Setup:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/9fiCf]

Top one is my normal setup

Bottom one is the setup that I've tried

It didnt help.

thanks for help

Comment: *Exactly* what do you mean when you say "1.11 mb/s"? This makes a difference, because 1.11 megabytes per second plus a bit of Ethernet, IP and TCP overhead is pretty close to 10 megabits per second, which is the lowest Ethernet speed generally supported today. It is possible that something is causing the switch and laptop to negotiate a lower speed. (1.11 megabits per second would be far slower than any currently supported wired Ethernet standard, and by your mention of a switch I take it that your network is wired, not wireless, so congestion is not likely to be a significant issue.)

Comment: yes that's exacly what i said and yes i have 1.11 megaBytes per second on laptop , but what could cause to negotiate a lower speed?

Comment: Have you tried copying a large file (something on the order of .5-1GB size) from the desktop to the laptop? This might narrow it down to a LAN problem or a WAN problem. And if it plateaus at 10 mbit, you know its throttled.

Comment: you mean like copy thru USB or using LAN/Net?  ut like i said week ako when downloading bf3 it was goind normally 5mb/s

Comment: UPDATE now like the speed is normal agian 6.87mb/s i dont know why like i was on computer whole day and somewhere areound 21;00 it durned back to normal speed